# iPhone/iPad touch events Javascript LineChart

Tags: javascript, iphone, touch, mobile-safari, highcharts

I am trying to implement a linegraph with movable points in Javascript using [Highcharts](http://highcharts.com).
Using latest Chrome everything just works as expected.
However, when I look at it on my iPhone or iPad, the movable points wouldn't move at all.

This is due to the fact that mouse events are handled differently in mobile Safari.

`mousedown` becomes `touchstart`, `mousemove` becomes `touchmove`, etc.

I tried to map all the touchevents to their appropriate mobile equivalent but without much success. The points can be dragged, but the view is not updated...

Chrome working version: http://jsfiddle.net/MTyzv/3/

Mobile Safari version: http://jsfiddle.net/MTyzv/7/

**UPDATE**

Ok I narrowed the problem down a bit...
It seems like all the touch events are handled correctly, but the points jump to 0.0 as soon as they are moved. In addition to that, the graph is not "redrawn" after the initial touch.
See the updated version of this Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/MTyzv/11/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a usual issue for everyone who starts working with touch events.

TouchEvent supports multitouch, so there's not such a thing like `event.pageX`. TouchEvent contains three "TouchLists", its:

- event.touches
- event.targetToches
- event.changedTouches

Finally on those lists you can get a Touch pageX, pageY, etc. If you don't care about multitouch there's a common simplification, you can call event.targetTouches[0].pageX

I updated your demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/7UsbM/7/ now it works in both, touch-enabled devices and desktop browsers.

Don't forget to take a look at MDN reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Touch_events

Hope it helps.

Comment: Careful! According to this recent bug https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=179711 Chrome won't pass the crucial ontouchstart test `var hasTouch = 'ontouchstart' in window`, claiming that the event exists, disabling mouse dragging. Had me stumped for awhile...

Comment: I don't think it's a bug. There are more and more desktop computers with touch screen. That's the reason why desktop browsers support touch events too. However, keep in mind that when you detect touch events, you shouldn't neglect mouse events!

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing like drag for mobile, but you need to use touch events to this working.
Usually you need x,y co-ordinates to make logic, so make functions/classes that work on x,y position of mouse/ touch, than simply add events and get touch x,y or click x,y and call these functions.

```
$('div').bind('mousedown' , function(e)
{
   // get x,y code
   var y = e.pageY;
   var x = e.pageX;

   // pass to function down(x,y);
   down(x,y);
});


$('div').bind('touchstart' , function(e)
{
   // get x,y code
   var touch = e.touches[0];
   var y = touch.pageY;
   var x = touch.pageX;

   // pass to function down(x,y);
   down(x,y);
});

function down(x,y)
{
   // do something with x,y
}
```